Error when assigning Microsoft Graph permissions in Bicep
In Bicep, I am attempting to create a User Assigned Identity, and then assigning that identity a few scopes using the new Microsoft.Graph bicep capabilities:
resource sqlIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  location: location
  name: 'id-sqlserver-${environment}'
}

//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/templates/reference/oauth2permissiongrants?view=graph-bicep-1.0

resource graphPermissions 'Microsoft.Graph/oauth2PermissionGrants@v1.0' = {
  clientId: sqlIdentity.properties.clientId
  consentType: 'Principal'
  resourceId: sqlIdentity.id
  scope: 'User.Read.All GroupMember.Read.All Application.Read.All'
}

However, I get the following error message: The identity of the calling application could not be established. Another user tried that has elevated permissions but got the same error. How can I assign Microsoft Graph permissions using Bicep?

It is a bit confusing but:

clientId represents the objectid of the client application: in your case the managed identity
resourceId represents the objectid of the target resource: in your case the service principal of MS Graph in your tenant.

This should work:
extension microsoftGraph

param location string = resourceGroup().location
param environment string = 'wb'

// create a managed identity
resource sqlIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  location: location
  name: 'id-sqlserver-${environment}'
}

// Reference to the Ms Graph Service Principal in the tenant
resource msgraphSp 'Microsoft.Graph/servicePrincipals@v1.0' existing = {
  appId: '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
}

// Asiggned delegated permissions
resource oauth2PermissionGrant 'Microsoft.Graph/oauth2PermissionGrants@v1.0' = {
  clientId: sqlIdentity.properties.principalId
  consentType: 'AllPrincipals'
  resourceId: msgraphSp.id
  scope: 'User.Read.All GroupMember.Read.All Application.Read.All'
}


It looks like the application '<id>' you are trying to use has been removed or is configured to use an incorrect application identifier.  A Google search doesn't really show any evident solutions.

can you the MS Graph app in your tenant ?

sorry, can you readd your question? I suspect a typo.

ha sorry, i mean can you see the MS GRaph app in your tenant ^^

Yes and that is the correct appId. Strange.

Not the matter of Insufficient permissions, It's about oauth2PermissionGrants conception. Remember it is representing delegated permissions which have been granted for client applications to access APIs on behalf of signed-in users. So your resourceId in the bicep should be the APIs which your want to access, not the identity itself. the APIs resourceId such as 'Microsoft Graph' can be found in AAD Enterprise Application with copy its objectId.
So your bicep should something like below:
main.bicep
provider microsoftGraph

param location string = resourceGroup().location

param environment string = 'wb'

resource sqlIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  location: location
  name: 'id-sqlserver-${environment}'
}

//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/templates/reference/oauth2permissiongrants?view=graph-bicep-1.0

resource graphPermissions 'Microsoft.Graph/oauth2PermissionGrants@v1.0' = {
  clientId: sqlIdentity.properties.clientId
  consentType: 'Principal'
  resourceId: 'xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx'
  scope: 'User.Read'
}

After deployment complete, which means the sqlIdentity can on behalf of your to access the microsoft graph api with Read permission.

Just remember that this resource id comes from the API provided by Microsoft or the API you developed and exposed yourself, not the identity you created.


The object ID for MS Graph API in my tenant is 5dfd50b7-dd12-4fca-afba-114d0947f81f. I don't think those are same across tenants. The application/client ID for MS Graph API is always 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 though. You can find that service principal and use its object ID in the permission grant.

@juuas your are right. I have just check it and revised my answer. thank you.

@juunas can you elaborate on how I would find that? Would that be a Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/identities resource type? Or could I use a Microsoft.Graph/applications type in Bicep?

I haven't looked into the Bicep support, but it is a "service principal" in Graph API. Applications are a different type.

This is how I ended up getting this to work for a similar use case.
// entra-external-setup.bicep
extension microsoftGraph

param appName string
param deployEnvironment string

targetScope = 'tenant'

var applicationRegistrationName = '${appName}-${deployEnvironment}-app-01'

var redirectUris = deployEnvironment == 'prod' 
  ? ['https://app.${appName}.io'] 
  : ['https://${applicationRegistrationName}.azurewebsites.net', 'https://localhost:44305']

resource microsoftGraphServicePrincipal 'Microsoft.Graph/servicePrincipals@v1.0' existing = {
  appId: '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
}

resource applicationRegistration 'Microsoft.Graph/applications@v1.0' = {
  uniqueName: applicationRegistrationName
  displayName: applicationRegistrationName
  web: {
    redirectUris: [for item in redirectUris: '${item}/sigin-oidc']
    implicitGrantSettings: {
      enableIdTokenIssuance: true
    }
  }
  requiredResourceAccess: [
    {
     resourceAppId: microsoftGraphServicePrincipal.appId
     resourceAccess: [
       { id: '7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182', type: 'Scope' } // offline_access
       { id: '37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e', type: 'Scope' } // openid
     ]
    }
  ]
}

resource applicationRegistrationServicePrincipal 'Microsoft.Graph/servicePrincipals@v1.0' = {
  appId: applicationRegistration.appId
}

resource grants 'Microsoft.Graph/oauth2PermissionGrants@v1.0' = {
  clientId: applicationRegistrationServicePrincipal.id
  consentType: 'AllPrincipals'
  resourceId: microsoftGraphServicePrincipal.id
  scope: 'openid offline_access'
}

